# jquery isotope load

Tags: jquery, load, jquery-isotope

I using isotope plugin for jquery, this works good if is static html blocks:

```
HTML:

<body>
    <div id="target">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body>

JS:

$('#target > *').isotope([needle options]);
```

but, if i use "load" to load content into #target, isotope ignore them.

```
JS:
$('#target').load('file',function()
{
    $('#target > *').isotope([needle options]);
}
);
```

please help, it's very important.

Answer (score 2):

You can instance onload various div items retrieved by your `load`.

See [insert method](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/methods.html#insert) from the isotope docs.

```
$.ajax({
  url: file,
  success: function( data ) {
  $('#target').isotope('insert', data);
  }
});
```

Comment: ps. did not test the code, its more to give you some idea of how you should do this.

Comment: Ok after loading file in console typed this:

Uncaught TypeError: Object (here is all html code from loaded file(why? I don't know)) has no method 'filter'